# Set posts per page for parent category and it's all children

Tags: query, pre-get-posts

I am trying to use the following function to set the number of posts per page for a specific category and all it's children:

```
function hbg_category_query( $query ) {
if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category()) {
    if (is_category( '14' ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( 14, get_query_var('cat'))) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 32 );
    }
}
return $query;
}
```

It works for the parent category and it works if I specify the ID(s) of the child categories, but I am trying to catch all the child categories (even new ones).

Can anyone clarify what I am misunderstanding about how this works?

Thank you,

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`get_term_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children).

```
function hbg_category_query( $query ) {
  if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category()) {
    $categories = get_term_children(1,'category');
    $categories[] = 1; // add your special category

      if (is_category($categories)) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 32 );
      }
  }

  return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','hbg_category_query');
```

Barely tested, but I think that will work.

Comment: Yes, I confirm this works. Thank you so much for taking the time to help!